# If F is a commutator subgroup to G then prove that G/F is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand some basic Algebraic topology for Physics.

The relation between the fundamental group and the homology group is given by an isomorphism $\phi:\pi_1(|K|)/F\to H_1(K)$. Where F is the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(|K|)$ and K is a connected simplicial complex.

As I understand from the internet the map $\psi:\pi_1(|K|)\to\pi_1(|K|)/F$ is called abelianization of the fundamental group. It makes sense intuitively that if you quotient out all the non-commutating commutators you get a new relation i.e $(x_i;r_m)\to(x_i;r_m,[x_i,x_j])$. But how do you prove that $\pi_1(|K|)/F$ is abelian?

Comment: Because $[a][b]=[b][a][a^{-1}b^{-1}ab]=[b][a]$, does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer presumes you know the basics of group theory:

With your notation, observe that $\;G/F\;$ is abelian iff

$$\forall\,x,\,y\in G\;,\;\;xFyF=yFxF\iff xyF=yxF\iff (yx)^{-1}(xy)=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=:[x,y]\in F$$

But $\;F=G'=\;$ the commutator subgroup of G is generated precisely by all the commutators $\;x,y\;$ , as $\,x,y\;$ run over all the possible choices of elements in G...

Answer (score 1):

Suppress the quotient map $G\to G^{ab}$ in the notation. You can calculate

\begin{align} gh= gh1 = gh(h^{-1}g^{-1}hg) = hg \end{align}

in $G^{ab}$.